# Accepting PHP in a textarea may be too dangerous, trying to find another solution

Tags: php, python, arrays, input

I'm having an issue with finding some way of accepting the data below, and being able to parse it as arrays, etc. in PHP or Python.

```
$data = array(
    'full_name' => array('name'=>'Full Name', 'type'=>'textarea'),
    'company' => array('name'=>'Organization', 'required'=>true),
}
```

There are many more fields in that inner array and there isn't a set order as to how they appear.

Is there any way for me to parse a users input from a textarea and be able to use it as the array that it is? Or any other ideas on what to do with it?

Comment: you can allow them to post all the code you want, just html encode/escape the code so that what they post doesn't get immediately executed or run against the server.  Then you can parse it later and execute it and blow away your own stuff.  At least you'll know who ran the bad code that was injected.

Comment: Does it need to be input as arrays? If not, YAML would do a pretty good job.

Comment: @MikeMcMahon - I think the idea is that the arrays _are_ subsequently run as PHP, which is why I think another format should be accepted, and converted to array afterwards.

Comment: What's your reason for allowing straight PHP to be submitted by the user? How about using an interface where users can add "boxes" and enter the contents of the arrays?

Comment: @halfer absolutely, i was being a bit facetious :)!  The best bet is to do as was advised, using JSON or some other intermediary safe format.

Comment: @phpdev The output you see there is what one of my config-creator scripts outputs. I wanted to make it easier on someone using it, say someone who doesn't understand the code and just paste it to my config-creator and have all the data pre-populated so they can easily edit anything they want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about using JSON as an input format? That could be parsed easily, and wouldn't be a security risk.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you need,

This is what json was made for!

take a look at this quick example using your data http://codepad.org/17jxHjeY

you can pass objects and arrays easily.

Mike

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can use `ast.literal_eval` to parse a string into a dictionary safely.